# Angular component template inheritance

Tags: html, angular, templates

Situation is as follows:

I have a outer component, and have other components inside that. Lets say i created a baseComponent that has a border and a close button.
Inside that i want to show stuff. This can be a lot of components, but they all need to have a border and a close button.

So i thought something like this first:

```
<baseComp><imageComp></imageComp></baseComp>
<baseComp><textComp></textComp></baseComp>
```

The baseComponent should handle the border and the close button.

But the template of the baseComponent looks like this:

```
<div class="border"><img class="closebutton">...</div>
```

But how do i get something on the three dots?

How does this nest?

I want the result to look like this:

```
<div class="border"><img class="closebutton"><imageComp></imageComp></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [content projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection). Using `<ng-content></ng-content>`, you can project your inner component (`<imageComp></imageComp>`) into the template of your parent component. Your parent component would look something like:

```
<div class="border"><img class="closebutton"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
```

And your child component would look something like:

```
<baseComp>
   <!-- Contents of ImageComp -->
</baseComp>
```